# Overloading operators in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following problem: I wish to create and use numpy array with slight change in operator `[]`. I understand so far it is done by the method `__getitem__(self, index)`. However I am unable to figure how to do it so I declare an array that is "numpy array" in every aspect except of that one issue (say for sake of example I want `array[i]` to be interpreted as `array[i-1]`

I tried to solve it following way:

```
class myarray(np.ndarray):
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self[index+1]

k = np.linspace(0, 10, 10).view(myarray)
```

though it's not really working

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: `array = array[1:]` ?

Comment: Subclassing `ndarray` is a complicated task. See the code for `np.matrix` or masked array to see how involved that is. I'd start with a set of functions that manipulate an array in the desired way.  Develop a class only when it is clear that that will make your code clearer.

Comment: Also read the `lib.index_tricks.py` file to get ideas on how use indexing syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first, that the index can be also a `tuple` (not just an `int`). 
The other is, that in the return of your function you are getting the item with `[]`, which also uses **getitem**. This will lead to an infinite recursion. You have to use the function of the parent class with `super()`

```
import numpy as np


class myarray(np.ndarray):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            index = index[0] + 1,
        else:
            index += 1
        return super(myarray, self).__getitem__(index)

my_k = np.linspace(0, 10, 10).view(myarray)
k = np.linspace(0, 10, 10).view(np.ndarray)
print(my_k)
print(k)
```

Comment: But for your example I would not recommend to subclass the array just because of this. Also you would have to overwrite delitem, setitem and slicing to be consistent with your indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **onodip** answer, I've solved my initial problem.
It was slightly different from what I posted, I've learnt to be more specific in future ( not to ask by an example).

I originally wanted to iterate over matrix "in loops" - making n+1 index point to 0 and so forth for all indices - in other words considering them modulo shape.

```
import numpy as np


class myarray(np.ndarray):

def __getitem__(self, index): 

    if isinstance(index, tuple):
        new_index = tuple(index[i] % super(myarray, self).shape[i] for i in range(len(index)))
    else:
        new_index = index % super(myarray, self).shape[0]

    return super(myarray, self).__getitem__(new_index)


my_k = np.linspace(0, 10, 10).view(myarray)
print(my_k)
print(my_k[7])
print(my_k[17])
```

It's been a great lesson for me. Thanks all for answers and your time!